# What is the best way of storing session geolocation results from an IP using rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, geolocation, ip-geolocation

I'm working on a location based app and I'd like to store the location of a user from their IP address in rails. I'm using geokit currently and I'm able to get the location via the IP of the user but I'm wondering what the best way to store this information is without storing to the database (so first time/unregistered users can benefit from the location features without being registered/logged in).

The best example I can give is how Groupon or LivingSocial "know" where you are the first time you visit their apps. They get your location via IP and probably store it in a session. Is this the best way? If so, how do I go about it using rails/geokit?

Let me know if you need more info. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is there any reason you can't push it into the user session and refer to that in the absence of a registration? You could also create a caching table that associates physical IPs with locations and refer to that as well.

Comment: I suppose I could. However I'm not too familiar with sessions and rails. Any tips on the best way to do this (is it as simple as session[:city] = geo.city?). Also, what is the best way to store this session for a first time user that might visit any page on the app?

Comment: Sessions are really good at storing simple bits of text or numbers, but not very good at serializing entire models. If you keep your geographic information in those formats you'll be fine. For example: `session[:loc] = "#{lat},#{long}"`